# How to use the standard (non-dictionary) brute force attack on FTP in THC-Hydra?

Tags: brute-force, ftp

In the process of attempting to secure my local LAN, I have determined that I am at little risk of a dictionary brute-force attack.

This being said, a standard brute-force attack which involves cycling through every possible password in existence is (although not exactly subtle) a very dangerous threat.

I have downloaded THC-Hydra, however I can't find any tutorial or how-to website which actually explains how to use any other function aside from the dictionary attack method, which is really limited to easy passwords:

**How do I launch a standard (non dictionary) brute force attack on FTP with THC-Hydra?**

Comment: A long and randomly chosen password is a perfect defence against a brute-force attack. Suppose the attacker can try a billion possible passwords per second. If your password has 16 characters and uses a set of 90 possible characters (upper and lower case letters, digits and punctuation) then it will on average take the attacker 294 trillion years to brute-force their way in. Use good passwords, and then don't worry about brute-force attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to perform a brute force attack without a dictionary use "-x MIN:MAX:CHARSET", i.e "-x 3:3:a"

The -x switch defines the character set that will be used, instead of the -p switch which would have pointed at the dictionary.

> -P "try password PASS, or load several passwords from FILE"

To launch the attack on a FTP server just place ftp in the protocol section of the URL, followed by the target IP address.

For example;

```
root@find:~/Desktop# hydra -t 10 -V -f -l root -x 4:6:a ftp://192.168.67.132
```

> -t "run TASKS number of connects in parallel (per host, default: 16)"
>
> -V "verbose mode / show login+pass for each attempt / debug mode"
>
> -f "exit when a login/pass pair is found"
>
> -l "LOGIN or -L FILE  login with LOGIN name, or load several logins from FILE"
>
> -x "MIN:MAX:CHARSET password bruteforce generation"

[Good blog post about this.](http://blog.pusheax.com/2014/01/dictionary-and-brute-force-attack-using.html)

Another link that may help is [Hydras page from tools.kali.org](http://tools.kali.org/password-attacks/hydra), which has a lot of good information including full syntax, beyond the examples above.

Hope this helps.